# Highlighting a active Segmented Control + adding a border around the active segment

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a boarder around only the selected SegmentedControl item. The code that I have is creating the border that I am looking for, however it is creating this for both buttons in the segmented Control:

Here is the code:

```
sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
sender.layer.borderWidth = 4
```

I am trying to only show a border around the selected SegmentedControl.

I believe that I will need to use either setSelected or isSelected to try and only have a border around the active controller. Just need a little more guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UISegmentedControl` has subViews for each of its buttons, which you can access by its `subViews` array:

```
(mySegmentedControl.subViews[mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex] as! UIView).layer.borderWidth = 4
```

Of course, you have to set it back to the normal borderWidth when the selection changes.

Comment: Awesome. Thank You. Just needed to research more into this.

Comment: Am I suppose to be putting this in the IBAction? I am getting a build failed issue when I try to run this instance with no runtime error indication.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is customize segmentedControl.

Set a border image for segmentedControl for "UIControlStateSelected"

```
setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:
```